# VS code autocomplete doesn't work in another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As I mentioned above autocomplete works in script for unity . But then ı created another script.
And autocomplete doesn't work for this script. I couldn't solve why.

[Works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm5nv.png)

[Doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Fu0.png)

Thanks advance for your interest

Comment: have you tried closing VS code and reopening? this happens to me pretty often and just restarting VS reloads the intellisense.

Comment: Of course I did. I reopened many times. But didn't fix